# Не работает получение geolocation на локальном сервере

Tags: yandex-maps-api, firefox, yandex-maps-jsapi

Выполняю такой код на локальном сайте (`Open Server`):

```
ymaps.ready(function() {
    ymaps.geolocation.get();
}
```

Браузер выводит в консоль сообщение:

> Получение Geolocation может быть выполнено только при защищенном соединении.

Разве на локальном сервере не должно работать?

---

Проблема замечена только в `Firefox`, в остальных браузерах нет ошибки.

Comment: Похоже, что он ругается на http - многие браузеры разрешают геолокацию только на сайтах с https. В JS API при автоматическом способе геолокации или с провайдером 'browser' геолокация делается средствами браузера.

Comment: @Reni, а почему только в `Firefox` не работает? Может быть, это как-то в настройках активируется?

Comment: не знаю, попробуйте геолокацию с провайдером 'yandex' - она менее точная, но должна тут сработать.